# How can I jump to specific point in a HTML file in my WebView?

Tags: android, html, search, webview

I loaded a HTML file in my WebView. How can I jump to specific location in this HTML file (not an anchor).
Lets say I want to jump to specific string "abcde" in my HTML file.
How can I do it?